# Adding new rows with existing data using SQL

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

[image: Table1]

And all I want to do is add two new rows per PersonID i.e.

[image: Table 2]

These are just small snip bits from the actual table, as this table contains large amount of data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: so essentially you want to duplicate each row based on personID?

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: It is completely unlear what you're asking about. Please describe what are the rules which define adding rows (by the way in question you wrote columns) to table.

Comment: Please also tag your question to make clear what DBMS you are using.

Comment: @aron9forever - I wouldn't say I want to duplicate each row. Each person is now required to have two additional rows (two extra jobIDs). Initially they had 10 jobs associated to them now two extra jobs have been created and hence existing data needs to updated to reflect this.

Comment: @Kacper - apologies post amended

Comment: `Any help would be greatly appreciated.` ... Any explanation about the rules for adding data would also be appreciated.

Comment: What db you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT`?

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (ID, PersonID, JobID, Verified)
SELECT NULL, PersonID, MAX(JobID) + 1, 0
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY PersonID
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, PersonID, MAX(JobID) + 2, 0
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY PersonID
```

**Explanation:**

Inserting `NULL` for the `ID` column should force the database to assign the next sequence, assuming that `ID` be an autoincrement column.  If it is not, then maybe consider changing this.  For each of the new records, the `JobID` sequence is just continued, hence my use of `n+1` and `n+2`.  And you seem to be using zero as the default value of `Verified`, so this was hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's replies/comments.

I managed to resolve my question by using a CURSOR (see below). It's not brilliant but it does the job.

[image]